# Interpret output of TF lite on object detection API

Tags: android, python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am using Object detection api to train on my custom data for a 2 class problem.
I am using SSD Mobilenet v2. I am converting the model to TF lite and I am trying to execute it on python interpreter. 
The value of score and class is somewhat confusing for me and I am unable to make a valid justification for the same. I am getting the following values for score.

`[[ 0.9998122   0.2795332   0.7827836   1.8154384  -1.1171713   0.152002
  -0.90076405  1.6943774  -1.1098632   0.6275915 ]]`

I am getting the following values for class:

`[[ 0.          1.742706    0.5762139  -0.23641224 -2.1639721  -0.6644413
  -0.60925585  0.5485272  -0.9775026   1.4633082 ]]`

How can I get a score of greater than 1 or less than 0 for e.g. `-1.1098632` or `1.6943774`.
Also the classes should be integers ideally `1` or `2` as it is a `2` class object detection problem

I am using the following code

```
    import numpy as np
    import tensorflow as tf
    import cv2

    # Load TFLite model and allocate tensors.
    interpreter = tf.contrib.lite.Interpreter(model_path="C://Users//Admin//Downloads//tflitenew//detect.tflite")
    interpreter.allocate_tensors()

    # Get input and output tensors.
    input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
    output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

    print(input_details)
    print(output_details)
    input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
    print(input_shape)
    # change the following line to feed into your own data.
    #input_data = np.array(np.random.random_sample(input_shape), dtype=np.float32)

    input_data = cv2.imread("C:/Users/Admin/Pictures/fire2.jpg")
    #input_data = cv2.imread("C:/Users/Admin/Pictures/images4.jpg")
    #input_data = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\FlareModels\\lessimages\\video5_image_178.jpg")
    input_data = cv2.resize(input_data, (300, 300)) 

    input_data = np.expand_dims(input_data, axis=0)
    input_data = (2.0 / 255.0) * input_data - 1.0
    input_data=input_data.astype(np.float32)
    interpreter.reset_all_variables()
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)
    interpreter.invoke()
    output_data_scores = []
    output_data_scores = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[2]['index'])
    print(output_data_scores)

    output_data_class = []
    output_data_class = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[1]['index'])
    print(output_data_class)
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is caused by the wrong input image channel order. Opencv `imread` reads images in 'BGR' format. You can try adding

```
input_data = cv2.cvtColor(input_data,  cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

to get a 'RGB' format image and then see if the result is reasonable.

Reference: [ref](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/5122#issuecomment-444759113)

Answer (score 0):

The output of tflite model requires post-processing. The model returns a fixed number (here, 10 detections) by default. Use the output tensor at index 3 to get the number of valid boxes, `num_det`. (i.e. top `num_det` detections are valid, ignore the rest)

```
num_det = int(interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[3]['index']))
boxes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])[0][:num_det]
classes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[1]['index'])[0][:num_det]
scores = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[2]['index'])[0][:num_det]
```

Next, the box coordinates need to be scaled to the image size and adjusted so that the box is within the image (some visualization APIs require this).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(boxes)
df['ymin'] = df[0].apply(lambda y: max(1,(y*img_height)))
df['xmin'] = df[1].apply(lambda x: max(1,(x*img_width)))
df['ymax'] = df[2].apply(lambda y: min(img_height,(y*img_height)))
df['xmax'] = df[3].apply(lambda x: min(img_width,(x * img_width)))
boxes_scaled = df[['ymin', 'xmin', 'ymax', 'xmax']].to_numpy()
```

Here's a [link](https://github.com/ChrystleMyrnaLobo/tflite-object-detection/blob/master/inference.py) to an inference script with input preprocessing, output post-processing and mAP evaluation.